# Read in multiple columns with csv readin

Tags: csv, python-2.7, import, time-series, multiple-columns

Maybe I am just being picky but as a Matlab user trying to convert I am really having trouble with importing data.  I can't seem to read in more than two columns of data with a CSV read in.  Here is the coding I am using

```
x,y = [],[]
csv_reader = csv.reader(open('Data.csv'))
for line in csv_reader:
    x.append(line[0])
    y.append(line[1])
```

If I use Data.csv with more than 2 columns, I can't seem to return anything from the 3rd column and up so I have to read in several csv files to get the data I want.

I also would like to bring up the point that I am only using CSV format because I can't figure out how to import anything else.  Again, as a previous Matlab user, I prefer to copy a spreadsheet into a .txt file and import that.  Any direction on that would also be greatly appreciated.  Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

This worked fine for me as long as I kept adding variables, i.e. z=[] and z.append(line[2]), and so on... Maybe I am misunderstanding the questions?

```
import csv
x,y,z = [],[],[]
csv_reader = csv.reader(open('Data.csv'))
for line in csv_reader:
    x.append(line[0])
    y.append(line[1])
    z.append(line[2])
```

If you copy from a spreadsheet and paste to a text file, you can open('Data.txt') and split each line with \t, if that is what is the separator between columns.

```
xx,yy,zz = [],[],[]
fromtextfile = open('Data.txt')
#(append each list) for 
 #item in the line, split by tabs, into a list for line in the file
[(xx.append(item[0]),yy.append(item[1]),zz.append(item[2])) \
 for item in [line[:-1].split('\t') for line in fromtextfile]]

#or

xxx,yyy,zzz = [],[],[]
fromtextfile = open('Data.txt')
temp = []
for line in fromtextfile:
    temp.append(line[:-1])
for item in temp:
    templist = item.split('\t')
    xxx.append(templist[0])
    yyy.append(templist[1])
    zzz.append(templist[2])

fromtextfile.close()
```